# Scala Some redundant covariance

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, covariance, algebraic-data-types, scala-option

Scala standard library contains `Option` type.
The Option type itself is covariant type, this is obvious from its declaration `sealed abstract class Option[+A]`.

The questions are:
Why its constructor `Some` is also covariant
`final case class Some[+A](x: A) extends Option[A]`?
Is this somehow needed for pattern matching?
Or maybe it's done for better readability?

For me it seems redundant as I don't see any reason to use `Some` directly anywhere except in pattern matching but currently I can't see how it can depend on covariance.

Comment: It's not the _constructor_, that's covariant. It's the actual _class_ `Some`. 
If it wasn't covariant, then `Some("foo")` would not be a subclass of `Some(new Object)`.

Comment: @Dima I find this confusing, since `Some("foo")` and `Some(new Object)` aren't actually classes... But indeed, it makes sense that `Some[String]` is a subtype of `Some[AnyRef]`.

Comment: @Dima I meant data constructor of algebraic data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to understand that, as @Dima said, `Some[T]` is not a constructor but a subclass for `Option[T]`.

Once we have established that, the questions with variance are always easier to solve with `Dog` and `Animal`:

Is `Some[Dog]` a `Some[Animal]`? I think you'll agree that the answer is yes.

Pragmatically, it won't change much, since you'll seldom work with `Some[Dog]`, but rather with `Option[Dog]`, but it may occur (say when you use an `unapply` of a case class whose signature returns a `Some[Tuple]`), so why not add the variance while we're at it?

Comment: Could you please provide a more precise example with unapply method. Why should unapply return Some[Tuple] instead of Option[Tuple]? But yes, if we can use covariance just in case why shouldn't we. I thought that there could be another reason for that.

Comment: A better question to ask may be why anything at all is covariant? I mean, `Option` could be invariant too. In java, for instance, everything is invariant, and it works. So, why bother? The answer, of course, is because it makes sense. If  `Dog` is a subclass of `Animal`, then `Some[Dog]` should be a subclass of `Some[Animal]`. If it isn't, it's just wrong.

Comment: @Dima I understand what covariance means and also know that in java everything is invariant, so you're saying that there is some unspoken rule that data types in scala are covariant by default if there is no other reason for them to be invariant or contravariant?

Comment: @andrii.ilin Not everything should be made covariant, but if it passes the test with `Dog` and `Animal`, it most usually should be.

Comment: @andrii.ilin I did not say anything about any unspoken rule :) All I am saying is that, if you understand the reasons for `Option` to be covariant, then you should also understand those for `Some` (and also `Seq`, `Future` etc.), because all those reasons are the same - it just makes sense from data modeling perspective.